Including hidden link in CV to directly download the PDF of a document
I have the pdf copies of all my lab project reports and I want to provide a link to them in my CV using LATEX. How can I just add an external link of the downloaded PDFs in a way that the reader will just click on the word and the pdf of the lab reports will open up?

do want to embed the reports into the PDF or do you want to provide an url to a server location?

The 'Related' section on the right of this page may give some pointers, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85606/creating-pdf-with-external-link-to-open-another-pdf?rq=1 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25919/external-html-link-to-a-specific-page-of-a-pdf-file?rq=1.

usepackage{hyperref}, and its \url{}
